# URL types with multiple bundle identifiers for iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, url-scheme

I'd like my iOS project to handle multiple URL types and multiple bundle identifier, so I can install 2 versions of the app on the same device.

I have 2 different bundle IDs: com.mycompany.myapp and com.mycompany.myapp-test

I'm registering 2 URL types for both bundle identifiers in the Info.plist file

[image]

I generate 2 builds with the 2 bundle identifiers and installing both apps on the same device. Then I'm trying to reach my apps using 2 urls: myapp://feed to open myapp and myapp-test://feed to open myapp-test.

However for some reason, I cannot open myapp-test and it always opens myapp when I click on both links.

There is certainly something wrong in the way I handle this so I'm wondering how I can manage multiple bundle ID with multiple URL scheme within the same Xcode project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two different `info.plist` files, one for each target, with the specific URL scheme that you want for the specific app.

You then add the appropriate `info.plist` the relevant target in Xcode.

iOS does not use the `identifier` to determine which urlscheme applies to the app. Where multiple apps declare support for the same URL scheme, which one will be launched is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can select `project`> `build setting` press '+' and add a new `User-Define Setting`. we named it `some_var` for this example. you can simply change the value of that for your different build configurations.

[image]

you can put the `some_var` value anywhere in info.plist file as `${some_var}`

[image]